# C++: Should I catch all exceptions or let the program crash?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, crash, minidump

I have a Windows service written in (Visual) C++ with a very detail logging functionality that has often helped me find the cause of errors customers are sometimes experiencing. Basically I check every return value and log what is going on and where errors are coming from.

Ideally, I would like to have the same level of detailed visibility into exceptions (like array out of range, division by zero, and so on). In other words: I want to know exactly where an exception is coming from. For reasons of readability and practicality I do not want to wrap every few lines of code into separate try/catch blocks.

What I have today is one general catch-all that catches everything and logs an error before shutting down the program. This is good from the user's point of view - clean shutdown instead of app crash - but bad for me because I only get a generic message from the exception (e.g. "array out of range") but have no idea where that is coming from.

**Wouldn't it be better to remove the catch-all and let the program crash instead?** I could direct the customer to have Windows create an application crash dump (as described [here](https://helgeklein.com/support/creating-an-application-crash-dump/)). With the dump file WinDbg would point me exactly to the position in the code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: It's not good for the customer if the app unexpectedly crashes, albeit gracefully. It's better if it never crashes at all. And, catch(...) makes debugging a nightmare as you said above. Initially it might be bad to have customers witness a hard crash, but as those get reported, they will become less and less frequent (in theory), until it approaches 0.

Comment: @RPGillespie: Thanks, that is more or less my reasoning, too. If I am not mistaken crashes are the only way I can find and fix areas of code where exceptions may be thrown.

Comment: There is no excuse for a divide by zero error or other logic error ever being raised in a well written c++ program. It's an indicator of sloppy program design.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Please elaborate how to guarantee such an error will never be raised.

Comment: Check your arguments before dividing. Use static assertions to ensure zero is never passed as a divisor. If your divisor is a user-supplied parameter, check it at the point where it enters your program and log a RUNTIME error at that point. similarly for bounds checks on container access. There is no excuse for an index being out of bounds. Check the size of the container before indexing into it.

Comment: @RichardHodges: This question is about finding where such things may have been forgotten. Or where exceptions may have been thrown in library code not written by me and I thus cannot control.

Comment: @HelgeKlein If you don't trust a library, wrap calls to it in your own well-behaved calls. It is your responsibility to check each and every piece of data that touches your code. The time to do that is just before it's allowed to touch your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a custom, vectored exception handler by calling [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx) .

This will get called whenever an exception gets thrown, and in it you can generate a stack trace that you can then save off for logging purposes.

Writing the code to do this is not completely trivial but not rocket surgery either.

I've never personally done it in C++, but I would be surprised if there weren't ready-built libraries that do this available somewhere, if you don't have the time or inclination to do it on your own.

Comment: AddVectoredExceptionHandler looks promising. It is not exactly well documented, though, and MSDN's example is explicitly for 32-bit only. Is there better documentation and sample code available anywhere?

Comment: I found the documentation adequate for what I needed to do. Feel free to ask specific questions about it, if you have, any and I (or someone else) will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw exceptions with description where the error occurred and why:

```
throw std::string("could not open this file");
```

If you do not want to write different descriptions for every possible error you can use standard macros __FILE__ and __LINE__:

```
#define _MyError std::string("error in " __FILE__ + std::to_string(__LINE__))
// ...
throw _MyError;
```

If source file name and line of the error is not enough and you need more information, for example stack trace or memory values, your program can generate a debug report. Google Breakpad is a C++ library that allows you to do that in a portable way. Class wxDebugReport from wxWidgets library is an alternative. On Windows the debug reports may include a minidump file that can be loaded in Visual Studio and allows you to analyse the error in a way similar to debugging.

Comment: Please ensure that anything you throw is derived from `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`. By throwing objects not ultimately derived from `std::exception` you undo all the good work put into the c++11 `<exception>` header.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't it be better to remove the catch-all and let the program
>   crash instead?

You can catch-all and

- Write a (more personal) message about the fatal error that occurred, forcing the application to be closed. Do not let the program continue: you don't know what happened, where. Continuing might cause damage to the user's data, follow up errors, etc.
- Tell the user to contact you with specifics as to what they did and what happened.
- Tell the user to include the log file your application has generated.

If you don't do something like this, then you might just as well remove the catch-all.

> For reasons of readability and practicality I do not want to wrap
>   every few lines of code into separate try/catch blocks.

And yet if you want your program to be able to recover, this is exactly what you have to do. What you could do is

- Tell the user what happened, perhaps what was wrong with the input that may have caused it. Don't make it sound technical.
- Save any data the user has entered so their work is not completely lost
- You know at which step the failure happened. Undo that step, i.e. throw away objects / data, and go back to the point before the exception.
- Restore data the user had entered from the second point so they don't need to repeat actions all over again.

The point being that your program can return to a valid state.